# Hide sprites out of GXT Chart area

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, gxt-charts

Have trouble with zoomed charts. Is there any solution to hide sprites which are below the X axis and in left of Y axis in Sencha gxt chart 4.0.2? [Example with chart data below x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcAD0.jpg)

Maybe there are some chart, axis or series property?

Comment: GXT 4.0.2 isn't available without paying for it (or agreeing to pay for it), but as I recall each Sprite has a clipRectangle property - can you assign that to the bounding box of the actual region of the chart?

Comment: Yes, it is not free. Thanks for idea. Will check that.

Comment: Note that it also isn't maintained - there are no developers working on it at Sencha, and support questions do not get answered (according to the other companies I've spoken to in the last year which still use it).

Comment: Just checked. Thank You very much. It works.